# Laravel form action

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a hard time setting up simple links/actions.

In my index view, I have this little form that I want to launch the getTest action in the ProjectsController when I click on the button:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('ProjectsController@getTest', $project->id))) }}
<button type="submit"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is the getTest function :

```
public function getTest(){
        echo "test";
        return 'test';
}
```

But this keeps getting me a `"Array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements"` error.

I tried making this work with a route. with this form open instead :

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['test_route', $project->id]]) }}
```

And this route :

```
Route::get('projects/test', array('as' => 'test_route', 'uses' =>'ProjectsController@getTest'));
```

But I still have the same error. 
I can't find any good doc on routing/sending to actions that don't give me this problem. I don't see what

Answer (score 0):

Your route doesn't need parameter, so I think this code is sufficient:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => 'test_route']) }}
```

Comment: I tried removing the parameter, it works, but now for an unknown reason it keeps calling my ProjectsController@index view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you are adding parameters to the action, but you are not managing those parameters in your routes, nor is your `getTest()` function accepting any parameters.  Another problem is you are setting your route as a `GET` route, but your form is going to be using `POST`.

It would be much easier instead on your form to use `Form::hidden('id', $project->id);` And then in your `getTest()` function, you could get the variable using `$id = Input::get('id');`.  You'd also be able to use your route name in your form as well.  `Form::open(array('route'=> 'test_route', method=> 'get'));`